# iOS 10.0.2 SSL issues, fixed in iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios, ssl

I'm struggling to figure out the reason iOS 10.0.2 fails to connect to an API server that complies with all the ATS regulations.

All browsers connections state that it is TLS1.2 and SHA2 256 encrypted connections with forward secrecy (ECDHE_RSA).

Now, the issue is that whenever the app that is installed on an iOS 10.0.2 device tries to connect to the API server - it fails with the message below, but when it tries the same thing on an iOS 10.1.1 device - the issue is simply gone.

I would not like to add the exception for the API as Apple will probably not approve the app but the message is not quite clear and I'm uncertain how to fix it.

```
UserInfo={
    NSErrorFailingURLKey=[hidden], 
    afHTTPRequestOperationError=<AFHTTPRequestOperation: 0x7c917ed0,
        state: isFinished, cancelled: NO request: 
        <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7c9073e0> { URL: [hidden] }, 
        response: (null)>, 
    NSUnderlyingError=0x7cf87430 {
    Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." 
    UserInfo={
            NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., 
            kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, 
            kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, 
            NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 
            kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, 
            kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7cf54810>,                 
            kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
...
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exact the same error codes/messages, but this happen sonly in production on user devices, on all 9.x and 10.x versions. On my own devices everything works ok, and all SSL tests and nscurl ATS testing pass...